# Using the abp framework, pass in the TransactionOptions parameter when starting a mongodb transaction

Tags: mongodb, abp

Using the [abp framework](https://github.com/abpframework/abp), is there any way to pass in the TransactionOptions parameter when starting a mongodb transaction(session.StartTransaction()), see [this](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/7f3ec72e1325e345cd01b075887d0991f771d3e9/framework/src/Volo.Abp.MongoDB/Volo/Abp/Uow/MongoDB/UnitOfWorkMongoDbContextProvider.cs#L187).

I use mongodb in replica set mode, and want to use secondary nodes for read operations, so I specify such a connection string:
`mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/BookStore?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred`,

but the read operations within a transaction will cause the exception:
`Read preference in a transaction must be primary`,

so I want to start the transaction Pass in such a parameter:
`session.StartTransaction(new TransactionOptions(readPreference: new Optional<ReadPreference>(ReadPreference.Primary)));`,

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Maybe you can consider to custom the `IConnectionStringResolver`.

https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.Data/Volo/Abp/Data/IConnectionStringResolver.cs

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give it a try.